# Webpage gets messy when the browser changes size

Tags: html, css

I'm not a very talented web designer, so I'm having trouble to make my webpage stay in tact when the browser changes its size. It gets all messy and it looks awful.

When the browser is at its full size, the page looks fine.

**This is how it looks like before re-sizing the browser:**

[image: Normal look of the page]

**And this is how it looks after making the browser smaller:**

[image: Distorted/messy look of the page]

This happens only when you re-size the browser horizontally.

This is my CSS: http://pastebin.com/SfKT0Eth

I can't figure out my mistake since I'm not very good in HTML/CSS. That's not my area so I'm lacking the knowledge to figure this out myself.

I would appreciate your help.

## EDIT

I fixed the problem with the sidebar and the dark content space. **What I'm failing to achieve is prevent the upper menu (top-nav) items to fall down when the screen gets small.**

I simply changed this in `#sidebar`:

```
width: 270px;
```

to

```
width: 19%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J3jm7/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi just i see your fiddle ... there are a few problems:

- Number one you're setting the `width` with % this takes it in relation with the browsers size, you can set `min-width` and `max-wdith` to avoid this problem.
- Try to put first in your html the box that is `float:left` and after the box `float:right`
- I don't understand why you use `postion:absolute` for the outer div.

View this demo with your Fiddle fixed **http://jsfiddle.net/J3jm7/15/**

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should really make a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your question as with css alone I can't really see what is going on.

Now as far as I can see you are using absolute values for width in some elements. You should take a look at using % values. Also you should look into media queries through css. For example your side bar would be better if it was hidden or position below your main window when the browser gets really small width.

You could achieve something like that by using something like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    #sidebar {
        display:none;
    }
```

This would hide the sidebar if the browser window get resized below 800px width
or

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    #sidebar {
        float:none;
        width:100%
    }
```

This would have the sidebar get below your main window and size it to the full width of its parent element if the browser window get resized below 800px width

The media queries should of course coexist with your rest of css

---

Ah, I see you've added a fiddle. well if you want to keep your sidebar at 270px width you could do this with the container

```
.container {
   width: calc(100% - 275px);
   ...
   ...
   }
```

Comment: That's not a big deal anymore; I'm satisfied with the result. I'm still failing to make the top-nav items stay in one row without breaking down and getting out of their black bar.

Comment: see my fiddle the top-nav is not breaking down ... just set a min-width

Comment: What do you want to happen when the browser gets resized ? If you don't mind having to scroll then you can use `min-width` and `max-width` as @Danko suggested. If you want the menu ti be reconstructed there are some things you could try. But what do you want to happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Very simply speaking it is hard to debug without a staging URL to look at. Anyway, your issue is because you are not using fluid development practices. Maybe try to google up how to develop fluid development. The idea is to use % and em and a base css font size. Also, you may wanna look at bootstrap3.

Comment: My webpage is on my local host and there is not way I could provide an URL for it. What I could do is provide this jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/J3jm7/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are coming in on the ground floor. The best resource to getting started in this area is Responsive Web Design by Ethan Marcotte. Check it out here: http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

Comment: Yeah I've heard about this term. I heard it makes a website ready for everything, including smartphones. Well, I don't need to go that far since my website will be accessed through a computer only.